# How to count max occurrences of rows meeting a certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to count max sequence of rows meeting a certain condition.
the example is this:

```
time    | value
10:00:01|   0
10:00:02|   0
10:00:03|   1
10:00:04|   0
10:00:05|   0
10:00:06|   0
10:00:07|   1
........| .....
```

i want the query to return the max occurrences of 0 uninterrupted by 1.
in the above example it will return 3.

is there a way to do this in sql?
Thanks.

Comment: What query did you try?

Comment: This is a version of the 'longest winning streak' problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variables to enumerate the sequential values.  Then use `order by` and `limit` to get the largest sequence number:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@v = value, @rn + 1,
                        if(@v := value, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @v := -1, @rn := 0) vars
      order by time
     ) t
where value = 0
order by seqnum desc
limit 1;
```